# Something is using my keyboard shortcut

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I am a Windows user. Currently there is a condition preventing me from using a  combination of keys:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

I suspect other key combinations might be affected too, as if something in the operating system has them already mapped, but I can't find any mapped actions or how to remove them.

Can anyone help me find out what these shortcuts may be bound to and how I may remove them?

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: What software is affected, and what is the shortcut supposed to perform? Be specfic.

Comment: I'm using windows 10 build 18363. It affect entire OS, so it's like the ctrl + shift + c is being hooked into certain action, but i dont see any action and such. I use the google chrome, it affect, even i play game and purposely tried to make a bind ctrl shift c or m, it still the same

Comment: `Ctrl`+`Shift` = _Switch the keyboard layout when multiple keyboard layouts are available_.